# Javascript unshift without returning size - React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I'm using unshift method from JavaScript inside render() method in a component in React and now the size of array is showing on page. Is there any method in JavaScript to put elements at the beginning without returning the size?

```
render() {
let cells = [];
code.....
return (
      <div>
        <Table padding="dense">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow className="compact" color="dark">
             {code...}
             {
              cells.unshift({ style: {}, fieldName: fieldNames.substr(3), extraOptions: {} })
             }
{ 
              cells.map(cell => {
                return <TableCell style={cell.style} key={`${cell.fieldName}`} {...cell.extraOptions}>{cell.fieldName}</TableCell>;
              })
            }
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
....
```

Comment: Can you add some code to your question, please?

Comment: it's likely you have it coded incorrectly.

Comment: Without seeing an sort of example, you could use destructuring: `[newElement, ...existingArray]`.

Comment: Why do you have that in your JSX to begin with? Why not just put it in the body of `render`?

Comment: [unshift](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/unshift) adds an element to the beginning of an array and returns ***the new length*** of the array. You're rendering this length value. The render function should be a pure function, i.e. no side-effects. Can you update your question to include a [Complete and Reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) code example so it is clearer what you are trying to do? You can use spread syntax to prepend, `[newItem, ...cells]`, but this won't update `cells` for later uses.

Comment: @BrianThompson he probably just wants a one-liner (although I agree with you)

Comment: @BrianThompson The <TableCell> is built inside the <Table> component and the code is on production. I don't have time to refactor all the code.

Comment: Thanks @BrianThompson it worked moving outside the render.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I moved the logic outside JSX as @Brian Thompson said.

```
render() {
let cells = [];
code.....
{
cells.unshift({ style: {}, fieldName: fieldNames.substr(3), extraOptions: {} })
}
return (
      <div>
        <Table padding="dense">
          <TableHead>
            <TableRow className="compact" color="dark">
{ 
              cells.map(cell => {
                return <TableCell style={cell.style} key={`${cell.fieldName}`} {...cell.extraOptions}>{cell.fieldName}</TableCell>;
              })
            }
            </TableRow>
          </TableHead>
....
```